SwiftUI MapKit MapPolygons remove strokes
I have a number of MapPolygons (hexagons) overlaid on a SwiftUI MapKit map.
                            ForEach(row.polygons, id:\.self) {poly in
                                MapPolygon(coordinates: poly)
                                    .stroke(lineWidth: 0)
                                    .foregroundStyle(.blue.opacity(0.4))
                                    .mapOverlayLevel(level: .aboveRoads)
                            }

Even though, stroke lineWidth is set to 0, the borders between touching (but not overlapping) hexagons are still showing. Setting stroke style to Color.clear has no effect either.
Is there a way completely remove the stroke border in MapPolygons?
I have no issue doing this on the web (mapbox, leaflet). Also doing a geometry union on these polygons is not a solution, as I want fill colour to act as the visual separator between polygons of different properties.
Current problem can be visualised in the image below:


You can use an alternative stroke initialiser:
.stroke(.blue.opacity(0.0), lineWidth: 0.0)


The issue persists regardless of the stroke initialisers used. I am beginning to sense that Apple draw MapPolygons as choropleth, but it is nowhere in the docs that I could find. I thank you for your response.
